# Can a map a folder to appear on my C:?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-explorer

This is a longshot, but is there a way to map a file or folder that is currently in G:\Dropbox\ to appear to a program that the files are in C:\Users\username\Dropbox\

Basically, a program is currently pointing to lots of manually ordered files in C:\Users\username\Dropbox\something.avi.  The files are now actually at G:\Dropbox\something.avi

But this program can't find them there, and unfortunately there is no re-linking, and also unfortunately this is a custom software solution for our company for which there is no replacement, and the software devs left the company to work on apps.

Like I said, I think this is a longshot, but if there is a solution for this, it will save us hours and hours of labor, or finding someone to decipher this program/scripts and rewrite the portions to allow re-linking.

Thank you kindly for your help, and let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2):

A [NTFS junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) will allow you to splice a directory from one place to another, but not individual files.

Comment: Thank you, this should serve my purposes as it just is looking in that directory for the files.  I'm researching it more right now.  I'd never heard of NTFS junction points.

Comment: And just to confirm, this worked perfectly.